# unable to fetch value from html form to my python code

Tags: python

I'm unable to fetch information from my html form to my python code. I checked the code many times but there doesn't seem to be a problem. Please check my code and tell me what's wrong. Thank you.

```
@app.route("/search",methods=["POST","GET"]) 
def search1():                                #python code
    var=request.form.get("search2")
    sear=str(var)
    print(var,sear)
    return " "
<html>                      <!--html code-->
<head>
    <title>hi there</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="font-family:verdana; font-style:italic;">Welcome to the book sea !!!....</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('search1') }}" method="get" align:"center">
        <input type="text" name="search2" placeholder="enter details">
        <button>search</button>
    </form>
    
</body>
```

Comment: you return, returns `" "` maybe you meant to use `""" <html>... """`. Does the above even run? Can you share logs?

Comment: `app.route(....)` is a decorator, So use `@app.route(....)`.

Comment: You can refer to this code https://github.com/Shivamseth005/login_using_python_flask, check server.py in this github repository

Comment: @DevanshSoni sorry, copying mistake.

Comment: @urban the above code ran perfectly, but instead of printing the value which i entered, it prints "none none".

Answer (score 1):

Change the "get" in your HTML to "post". Because the way your Flask route is set up, it doesn't allow for a variable to be passed using a get request.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search1') }}" method="get" align:"center">
```

to:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search1') }}" method="post" align:"center">
```

Also you might want to remove or edit `align:"center"` because it's not proper html. Add it in style="" attribute or remove it.

Also:

1. Add a route to display the search form
2. Check if the request is a post method since you're accepting both get and post
3. You can use `var=request.form["search2"]` instead of `var=request.form.get("search2")`

===========================================

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("search.html")

@app.route("/search",methods=["POST","GET"])
def search1():                                #python code
    if request.method == 'POST':
        var=request.form["search2"]
        sear=str(var)
        print(var,sear)
    return " "

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

==== search.html .. should be placed in the templates folder of your project ===

```
<html>                      <!--html code-->
<head>
    <title>hi there</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:verdana; font-style:italic;">Welcome to the book sea !!!....</h1>
<form action="{{ url_for('search1') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search2" placeholder="enter details">
    <button>search</button>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it didnt work, even after changing method to post it fetches nothing.

Comment: @stormcloak it should print out sear=str(var)
        print(var,sear) in your console.

Comment: it prints "none" in my console

Comment: @stormcloak I added the HTML. It's working fine on my end. Please update the question with your current code if it's still not working. Don't forget to create the templates folder and place search.html in it with the HTML code above.

Comment: after using var=request.form["search2"] it showed "400 bad request" error.

Comment: @stormcloak  What does your HTML look like? How are you rendering it?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by reinstalling the flask app. Thanks for your effort.